# python dropbox api - save token file?

Tags: python, api, authentication, dropbox

I want to avoid having to authorise this script over and over. In other words, when I launch the script from the terminal, it gives me a link I have to open in a browser then click on the 'Allow' button in the browser then go back to the terminal...I guess there's a way to save the authentication details but how?

```
# Include the Dropbox SDK libraries
from dropbox import client, rest, session

# Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developer website

APP_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
APP_SECRET = 'yyyyyyyyyyyy'
ACCESS_TYPE = 'dropbox'


sess = session.DropboxSession(APP_KEY,APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TYPE )

request_token = sess.obtain_request_token()

# Make the user sign in and authorize this token
url = sess.build_authorize_url(request_token)
print "url:", url
print "Please authorize in the browser. After you're done, press enter."
raw_input()

# This will fail if the user didn't visit the above URL and hit 'Allow'
access_token = sess.obtain_access_token(request_token)

client = client.DropboxClient(sess)
#stored_creds = open(CONF_DIR + self.TOKEN_FILE).read()
print "linked account:", client.account_info()

f = open('t.txt')
response = client.put_file('/uploaded_with_python.txt', f)
print "uploaded:", response

folder_metadata = client.metadata('/')
print "metadata:", folder_metadata

f, metadata = client.get_file_and_metadata('/uploaded_with_python',rev='362e2029684fe')
out = open('/uploaded_with_python.txt', 'w')
out.write(f)
print(metadata)
```

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------EDIT

I modified the script and it created the script however I still have problems reading the token file

```
# Include the Dropbox SDK libraries
from dropbox import client, rest, session

# Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developer website

APP_KEY = 'i4ffahjltei1bnu'
APP_SECRET = 'cjullao1iiymrse'
ACCESS_TYPE = 'dropbox'

#acces token file
token_file = open(TOKENS)
token_key,token_secret = token_file.read().split('|')
token_file.close()

sess = session.DropboxSession(APP_KEY,APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TYPE )

request_token = sess.obtain_request_token()

# Make the user sign in and authorize this token
url = sess.build_authorize_url(request_token)
print "url:", url
print "Please authorize in the browser. After you're done, press enter."
raw_input()

# This will fail if the user didn't visit the above URL and hit 'Allow'
access_token = sess.obtain_access_token(request_token)
#save token file
TOKENS = 'dropbox_token.txt'
token_file = open(TOKENS,'w')
token_file.write("%s|%s" % (access_token.key,access_token.secret) )
token_file.close()

client = client.DropboxClient(sess)

print "linked account:", client.account_info()

f = open('t.txt')
response = client.put_file('/uploaded_with_python.txt', f)
print "uploaded:", response

folder_metadata = client.metadata('/')
print "metadata:", folder_metadata

f, metadata = client.get_file_and_metadata('/uploaded_with_python',rev='362e2029684fe')
out = open('/uploaded_with_python.txt', 'w')
out.write(f)
print(metadata)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropb.py", line 14, in <module>
    token_file = open(TOKENS)
NameError: name 'TOKENS' is not defined
```

Comment: the error "`name 'TOKENS' is not defined`" says it all: that is because in your edit code, you've written the definition "`TOKENS = 'dropbox_token.txt'`" a few lines after you've used it first, which is the line "`token_file = open(TOKENS)`"... Just move the definition line earlier in your code, before the first usage line appears.

Comment: Do you really want to share the APPKEY and the APPTOKEN with the internet?

Answer (score 20):

You can write the access_token to a file:

```
TOKENS = 'dropbox_token.txt'
token_file = open(TOKENS,'w')
token_file.write("%s|%s" % (access_token.key,access_token.secret) )
token_file.close()
```

If you do that once, then afterwords you can use that token:

```
token_file = open(TOKENS)
token_key,token_secret = token_file.read().split('|')
token_file.close()

sess = session.DropboxSession(APP_KEY,APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TYPE )
sess.set_token(token_key,token_secret)
client = client.DropboxClient(sess)
```

Comment: The token file is saved however I got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropb.py", line 11, in <module>
    token_file = open(TOKENS)
NameError: name 'TOKENS' is not defined